# Proper way to request a retag?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

Over on SO several questions have been tagged as [compass](/questions/tagged/compass) when they should have been classified as [compass-css](/questions/tagged/compass-css) instead.  What's the proper process for requesting they get retagged properly?  I lack sufficient mojo to do it myself and I've flagged the questions, but that doesn't seem to be getting processed.  Needless to say, searching for help on style issues with the search gurus probably isn't efficient.

Comment: [tag:compass] has 257 questions, while [tag:compass-css] only has 15.  Why is your way the correct one?

Comment: Because compass is dealing with the lucene search utility and compass-css is the one dealing with css?  Thus the last sentence in the OP?

Comment: Ah, sorry.  I forgot to put on my secret decoder ring before I read the last sentence.

Comment: Which is what triggered my wanting to retag the questions, I was grovelling over the compass questions to see what sorts of problems people commonly ran into and because disoriented until I read the tag descriptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 4 ways:
1. if you got enough reputation : edit the question, and change tags
2. again if you got enough reputation, there is a retag option
3. if you do not have enough reputation (or logged as anonymous), you can still suggest the edit
4. flag the question

Answer (score 1):

You can suggest an edit yourself - as long as the tag you wish to use already exists. If you don't have enough reputation to create a tag the only thing you can do (apart from nothing) is raise a flag.

All flags will be looked at eventually, however, there's no guarantee that the moderator who sees your flag will agree.

Comment: It's pretty obvious that the questions are improperly tagged, but that does illustrate the point for opinion issues.